# How to Access a Movieclip variable through a separate Function AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-cs6, flash-cc

Hey Everyone as seen below I am trying to change the property of this Movie clip variable `currentHex` when it's called on using this line of code.

```
TweenMax.to(currentHex, 0.5, {scaleX:1.2, scaleY:1.2, ease:Back.easeInOut, repeat:1, yoyo:true, onComplete:resetGreyOut}); // tween animation
```

When the `onComplete`is activated and it calls on the function `resetGreyOut` I get a 'Access of Undefined Property Error' I understand it's because it's a separate function and it can't find that var so I'm wondering how to go about finding or rather accessing that variable to change it in the 'resetGreyOut' function:

```
private function resetHitTestHandler():void 
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < aMainHexArray.length; i++)
        {

            var currentHex = aMainHexArray[i]; // All Hexs

            if (resetHex.hit.hitTestObject(currentHex.hitBox) && bDragging) 
            {
                if (currentHex.sColor == "BLUE")
                {
                    currentHex.gotoAndStop("BLUE");
                }else
                if (currentHex.sColor == "RED")
                {
                    currentHex.gotoAndStop("RED");
                }else
                if (currentHex.sColor == "YELLOW")
                {
                    currentHex.gotoAndStop("YELLOW");
                }else
                if (currentHex.sColor == "PURPLE")
                {
                    currentHex.gotoAndStop("PURPLE");
                }else
                if (currentHex.sColor == "GREEN")
                {
                    currentHex.gotoAndStop("GREEN");
                }else
                if (currentHex.sColor == "WHITE")
                {
                    currentHex.gotoAndStop("WHITE");
                }else
                if (currentHex.sColor == "ORANGE")
                {
                    currentHex.gotoAndStop("ORANGE");
                }

                TweenMax.to(currentHex, 0.5, {scaleX:1.2, scaleY:1.2, ease:Back.easeInOut, repeat:1, yoyo:true, onComplete:resetGreyOut}); // tween animation
                bDragging = false; // So doesnt loop
                //Sound effect 
                if (bSoundIsOn)
                {
                    // Play finish sound 
                    matchSoundChannel = resetSound.play();
                }
                //Remove Sparks
                nSparks -= nReset;
                updateSparksCounter();
                //Remove reset hex
                resetHex.destroy();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the `resetGreyOut` Function:

```
private function resetGreyOut():void 
    {
        currentHex.gotoAndStop("GREY");
        trace("GREEEEEY");
    }
```

All help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can pass arguments to the **onComplete** handler: **onCompleteParams:[currentHex]**, so that handler should accept that one parameter: **function resetGreyOut(currentHex:MovieClip):void**

Comment: Also, instead of that whole big **if .. else** block you can just put a single line: **currentHex.gotoAndStop(currentHex.sColor);**

Comment: Thanks for this. I cleaned up that block of if else statements. Can't believe I never noticed that before haha. Have been doing that on most my projects in the past. Wow, didn't even know there was a onCompleteParams for GSAP. Should have looked more into that. Thank you so much for all your help Organis. You're awesome man.